# Auto-submit radio buttons in test page using timer

Tags: java, javascript, forms, jsp, servlets

I am developing a project in Java named to be "Student Assessment System" which is an online test taking system for students, coding part is completed, now in Test taking environment or take test page I want to insert a countdown timer say for 30 mins(this is the maximum time of test) So after 30 mins the page should be submitted automatically with the selected options irrespective of whether the user answered all questions or not, and also is it possible to make the page go full-screen after clicking "Start Test" button, if yes how? 
PS : All questions will be in the same page, no scenario of next and back buttons.
Also note that I am bounded by Javascript only, no jquery plz

Thanks in advance, awaiting for a speed response :)

Comment: Jquery is javascript.

Answer (score 2):

When time finishes, call the function

```
function submitIt()
{
  document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
}
```

For countdown Timer, [see this](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/)